# Deleting item from pandas dataframe if it is not in the list

Tags: python, pandas

I know I can use `"isin"`  to check membership. However my case is slightly more complicated.
Let's assume that I have a list like this

```
my_genre_list = ['pop', 'rock', 'indie', 'jazz']
```

My data frame looks like this:

```
genre
['funk', 'pop', 'jazz', '90s pop']
['jazz', 'pop', 'alternative', 'metal']
['pop/rock', 'hard rock']
```

I want to check whether different genres on genre column belongs to the list but I don't want to split the genre column into different columns because in my real database they are actually represent something different and there are more than 1000 elements in a single list.
What I want to get is this:

```
genre
['pop', 'jazz'] # for instance funk and '90's pop' are not in my_genre_list
['jazz', 'pop']
[]
```

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: In my dataframe, genre column consist of lists and there are other columns, let me add desired output also

Comment: check "isin" http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

Comment: Actually I checked and mentioned it in my question but I want to make it element wise in my case

Comment: pandas doesn't play well with these kind of objects. I don't think anything you can do with pandas here will outperform looping over each list, making a comparison and building another list. And of course it would be much more efficient if you store them in sets rather than lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want something like this:

```
df['genre'] = df['genre'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i in my_genre_list])
```